# How can I close Material SideNav by clicking on an element which has the RouterLink directive?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using [angular 4](https://angular.io) in combination with [angular material](https://material.angular.io).

I am using a sidenav container a router and a custom generated menu:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
<mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <app-menu></app-menu>
</mat-sidenav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Inside the menu component I am using default angular 4 router links:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <a mat-button [routerLink]="['/hero/', hero.id]" queryParamsHandling="merge">
      {{hero.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is to close the `Material sidenav` when clicking on one of those router links.

I can assure you that without the click event routing works fine, it just does not close my sidenav, because the router-outlet is inside the side navigation.

However, when I add a `(click)="sidenav.close()"` to the `a` my full page suddenly refreshed, instead of just following the router link.

I have tried many things, but I can't seem to figure it out, hope someone can help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I created a service so that the sidenav could be controlled from various components. I followed [this example](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2936#issuecomment-296305761).

Then it's a matter of watching the router for events and closing as needed. In app.component.ts:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  // close sidenav on routing
  this.sidenavService.close();
});
```

This doesn't work if you want to close the sidenav on *only* specific links, but the service itself would facilitate that.

Comment: Will you explain, how it works only for mobile devices

Comment: Just to add: you may not want to close on all router events. In my case I just do so when is a "NavigationEnd" event (you can check that doing `(event instanceof NavigationEnd)`. Also, in scenarios where you have different sidenav setups for large vs small screens, you may not want to close the menu for larger screens if you are using "side" mode.

Answer (score 41):

Here's a complete solution based off of Angular Material's schematics generated sidenav layout component. This answer improves on the previous ones by taking into consideration whether we are on a handset device or not, and making sure the sidenav only closes on a handset device.

A few points:

1. This component was generated by using Angular Materials [navigation schematics](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics#navigation-schematic).
2. I called my component `my-menu` however, you may use any other name.
3. The sidenav will only close if we are <s>not</s> on a handset device, this is done using the `rxjs` operator `withLatestFrom` combined with the `isHandset$` stream which was generated by the schematics.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-menu',
  templateUrl: './my-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-menu.component.css']
})
export class MyMenuComponent {
  @ViewChild('drawer') drawer: MatSidenav;

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.isHandset$),
      filter(([a, b]) => b && a instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(_ => this.drawer.close());
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Technically the component's view is only fully initialised after the lifecycle hook [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit), but I guess this works because a router event only gets sent after that anyway.

Comment: this code is difficult to understand, but it works. From angular 8+ you should use   `@ViewChild('drawer', { static: true }) drawer: MatSidenav;`

Comment: Thank you, works great. However, in my case, after closing the drawer, the menu button keeps having a darker color (in a circle shape around it). The menu button is within the <mat-toolbar> which is within <mat-sidenav-content>. And this circled colour seems to be linked to the ripple effet. Any idea how to fix this? (however once we click anywhere, the circle disappears, but I would prefer to have it disappear without any user's action).

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to make a service for this. This is a simple solution.

```
<mat-sidenav-container [hasBackdrop]="true">
                <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="sideNavigation">
                        <mat-nav-list>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="" (click)="sidenav.close()"> bar</a>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="/bar" (click)="sidenav.close()">foo</a>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="/foo" (click)="sidenav.close()">whatever</a>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="/something1" (click)="sidenav.close()">SomePage</a>
                                <a mat-list-item routerLink="/something2" (click)="sidenav.close()">Some Page</a>
                        </mat-nav-list>
                </mat-sidenav>
                <mat-sidenav-content>
                        <mat-toolbar color="accent">
                                <mat-icon (click)="sidenav.toggle()">menu</mat-icon> 
                                <div class="divider"></div>
                                <img class="img" src="../assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" (click)="goHome()" />
                        </mat-toolbar>
                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </mat-sidenav-content>
        </mat-sidenav-container>
```

All you do is add `(click)="sidenav.close()"` along with the `routerLink="/whatever/path/here"` works. This will close the `sidenav` on directing to a page.

Comment: you could define your links property in the ts file as an array and then loop on that array so you don't have to repeat `(click)="sidenav.close()"`

Comment: It's a good solution but I prefer (click)="drawer.close()" because '(click)="sidenav.close()" is not visually very nice.

Comment: I don't link this solution because you have to specify the behaviour on every link.

Comment: I like it, simple and clean

Comment: for those whom are complaining about the repeat, you can simply change `<mat-nav-list>` to `<mat-nav-list (click)="sidenav.close()">` and remove all the `(click)="sidenav.close()"` from `mat-list-item`

Answer (score 10):

add `(click)="sidenav.close()"` to mat-sidenav

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav" (click)="sidenav.close()">
```

Answer (score 5):

Inspired on @isherwood's answer I came up with a solution:

I created the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {

  public sideNav:MatSidenav;
  constructor() { }
}
```

I changed my app component to set the sideNav property in the above service.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  @ViewChild('sidenav') public sideNav:MatSidenav;
  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {      
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavService.sideNav = this.sideNav;
  }
}
```

Please note that it's very **important** to implement `OnInit` and to set the `sidenavService.sideNav` in the `ngOnInit` function.

You can then use your sideNavService anywhere you want. In my case I use it only in the components that I actually link in my side navigation menu.

Example:

```
 export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {      
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavService.sideNav.close();
  }
}
```

You'll probably want to do it on **change of a parameter** instead of on init, but you get the point.

Answer (score 3):

Just additional small info, if you want to close sidenav only on mobile viewport, just use `isHandset$` function check for the drawer state before you call the function:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@ViewChild('snav', { static: false }) usuarioMenu: MatSidenav;

isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = 
   this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }

  closeAllSidenav() {
    this.isHandset$.subscribe(isVisible => {
      if(isVisible) {
        this.myDrawer.close();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the proper way to do it. I did modify it slightly:

`ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(mergeMap(event => {
      return this.isHandset$;
    })).subscribe(isSideNavVisible => {
      if (isSideNavVisible) {
        this.sideNav.close();
      }
    });
  }`

Answer (score 1):

I tested another solution in case it is necessary to call a method, it seemed easier and more practical using `@ViewChild`, I'll leave it here in case anyone wants to.

**app.component.html:**

```
<mat-sidenav #snav mode="over" fixedTopGap="56">
  <mat-nav-list class="pt-0">
    <a mat-list-item (click)="closeAllSidenav()">
      Navigation Item
    </a>
  </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@ViewChild('snav', { static: false }) usuarioMenu: MatSidenav;

closeAllSidenav() {
  this.usuarioMenu.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**another way to close sideNav by clicking element**

component html

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
<mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/hero/', hero.id]" 
 queryParamsHandling="merge">
      {{hero.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</mat-sidenav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

component ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {



  @ViewChild('sidenav') matSideNav: MatSidenav;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
  ) { }


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.mat-list-item[href]')
      .forEach((el: HTMLElement) => {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
          this.matSideNav.close()
        })
      })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing a single line of code.
You only need to add **#sidenav (click)="sidenav.toggle()"** within your ***mat-sidenav*** tag. Thats all.